# Multiple footnotes at one point

Tags: formatting, footnotes

I'm trying to create multiple footnotes referencing from one point, that look like this:

> lorem<sup>1,2</sup>

Searching for "multiple footnotes" shows up almost exclusively solutions for multiple references to one footnote. Here I have two separate footnotes, pointing from one place. I also don't want to merge them into one, because I tried it and it looks ugly.

Currently I resolved it in a quick and dirty way, writing:

```
lorem\footnote{foot1}$^{,}$\footnote{foot2}
```

Which shows up in the resulting PDF just fine, but I feel somehow bad about it. Is there a better way to do it?

Answer (score 112, accepted):

Use the [`footmisc`](http://ctan.org/pkg/footmisc) package and its `multiple` option.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[multiple]{footmisc}

\textheight=80pt% only for the example

\begin{document}

Some text.\footnote{A footnote}\footnote{And another one.}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: And for use with hyperref see Holle's answer to [Incompatibility between footmisc-option multiple and hyperref](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/62091).

Comment: FWIW, I found that this setup (`footmisc` package with `multiple` option) has the first line of the footnotes indented, which was not desirable for me. Using the `fnpct` package (as @clemens suggested) kept my footnotes unindented. (I tried adding some of the `footmisc` options like `para` or `hang`, but they didn't quite match the default style I wanted.)

Comment: It's been a while, but I would like to add to @Stephen's comment: for my use case there was no incompatibility. It just worked 

Answer (score 93):

This (the `footmisc` solution) won't work if you also have the `hyperref` package loaded.  Either turn off hyperfootnotes `[hyperfootnotes=false]` as an argument to `hyperref`, or use `\textsuperscript{,}`.  This maintains the same font for the comma, whereas your workaround above inserts the math font, and it could be different.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) A tip: You can use backticks `\`` to [mark your inline code](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/863/how-do-i-mark-inline-code) as I did in my edit.

Comment: This is actually mentioned in the [`footmisc` documentation](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/footmisc/footmisc.pdf): "The `hyperref` package has ambitions to make hyperlinks from footnote
marks to the corresponding footnote body; naturally this causes grief to `footmisc`, and unfortunately no remedy is currently known. If you use `footmisc`, suppress `hyperref`'s hyper-footnotes, by loading it as: `\usepackage[hyperfootnotes=false,...]{hyperref}`. Further work on the interaction between the two packages is proposed, but not yet scheduled."

Comment: @doncherry footmisc uses its own command `\multfootsep`, which defaults to "comma in current text font".  it hasn't used a maths comma since 1997 (at least); this doesn't negate the point about hyperref compatibility, of course (hyperref wasn't publicly available when i wrote footmisc, and i never quite got around to retrofitting it).

Comment: Hey, I'm not entirely sure why, but this solution doesn't work even without the `hyperref` package. Any other ideas?

Comment: No problems here with `hyperref` in conjunction with `footmisc`.

Comment: @AmirSagiv I had this problem and noticed that the footmisc package only works when the footnotes are *actually* adjacent. I had a line break between my footnotes, which footmisc didn't catch. Make sure there aren't any spaces/linebreaks/etc between footnotes.

Answer (score 40):

Additionally to the mentioned `footmisc` and the solution “by hand” there are three more possibilities.

1. The [KOMA-Script](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/koma-script) classes offer the option `footnotes=multiple`:

   ```
   \documentclass{scrartcl}
   \KOMAoption{footnotes}{multiple}
   \textheight=50pt % for this example only
   \begin{document}
   Text\footnote{One}\footnote{Two}
   \end{document}
   ```

   [image]

   As this again is not compatible with `hyperref` KOMA-Script also offers the rather lengthy `\multiplefootnoteseparator`. The comma used in both cases is set by `\multfootsep` which is defined through

   ```
   \newcommand*\multfootsep{,}
   ```
2. The [`memoir`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/memoir) class natively supports multiple footnotes:

   ```
   \documentclass{memoir}
   \textheight=50pt % for this example only
   \begin{document}
   Text\footnote{One}\footnote{Two}
   \end{document}
   ```

   [image]

   Again this is not working together with `hyperref` so `memoir` also defines a macro for manual input, `\multfootsep`, which is defined like this:

   ```
   \newcommand*{\multfootsep}{\textsuperscript{\normalfont,}}
   ```
3. Then there is [`fnpct`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/fnpct) - a package that was [designed to offer a solution for the kerning between footnote marks and punctuation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/56094/5049). As a sideeffect it also enables multiple footnotes that are compatiple with `hyperref`:

   ```
   \documentclass{article}
   \usepackage{fnpct}
   \usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
   \textheight=50pt % for this example only
   \begin{document}
   Text\footnote{One}\footnote{Two}
   \end{document}
   ```

   [image]

Comment: Your answer and the información you share is unsurpassable.

Comment: Awesome that `fnpct` works with `enotez`!

Comment: Nice answer. However, automatic recognition in KOMA `scrbook` with `footnotes=multiple`does not seem to work for me. Adding `\multiplefootnoteseparator` manually between the footnotes works though.

Comment: Good answer - all I had to do was add `\usepackage{fnpct}` to my preamble.  Also works when using `hyperref`.

Comment: TOO GOOD, you saved my day (solution 3)!!!

Answer (score 34):

Here is a very easy way to implement it for oneself with only four lines of code.  One can redefine the `footnote`-command and have a look to the following command using `\futurelet`. If the next command is also a `footnote`-command a `,` is included. That's all. And it plays well with the `hyperref`-package.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\let\oldFootnote\footnote
\newcommand\nextToken\relax

\renewcommand\footnote[1]{%
    \oldFootnote{#1}\futurelet\nextToken\isFootnote}

\newcommand\isFootnote{%
    \ifx\footnote\nextToken\textsuperscript{,}\fi}

\textheight=3cm
\begin{document}

Text\footnote{First footnote}\footnote{Second footnote}\footnote{Third footnote} Text\footnote{Fourth footnote} Text

\end{document}
```

[image: multiple footnotes]

Comment: A nice tutorial on how to use `\futurelet`! This solution seems to be so clean and simple that I wonder what are it's drawbacks. I mean, why there is a dozen of packages and classes for multiple footnotes that all fail on the integration with `hyperref`?

Comment: Great solution, and nice not to have to load another package for something so simple.

Comment: Awesome solution. Still works.

Answer (score 1):

you could also use an apostrophe written in math-mode for that:

```
\newcommand{\hochkomma}{$^{,}$}
```

For Example:

```
Testing multiple footnotes with commas \footnote{foonote1}\hochkomma\footnote{foonote2}\hochkomma\footnote{foonote3}
```

It will look like:
[image: Output of the command]