# How to display two (or more) footnotes consecutively?

Tags: footnotes

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Multiple footnotes at one point](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/28465/multiple-footnotes-at-one-point)

How to put two footnotes consecutively?

A solution could be:

```
Some text\footnote{Footnote 1}$^,$\footnote{Footnote 2}
```

Is there a more elegant way to do this?