# hyperref changes footnotes of Koma script

Tags: hyperref, footnotes, koma-script, bidi

I defined footnotes to insert a colon between `\footnote{bla}\footnote{bla}`. But when I load `hyperref` this is destroyed. In addition KOMA removes space at the beginning of a footnote, while hyperref modifies this again. Please compare the results of compiling the following MWE:

```
\documentclass[footnotes=multiple]{scrbook}


\usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage{bidi}

%\KOMAoptions{footnotes=multiple}

\deffootnote[1.5em]{1.5em}{0mm}{\textsuperscript{\normalfont\thefootnotemark}}

\begin{document}

Test\footnote{%
first footnote
}\footnote{
Second footnote.
}\footnote{
  The point of writing this text is that I can insert this footnote here so that Ulrike can see how
  a footnote looks like. The lipsum package does not insert footnotes.
}\footnote{
  And if they did not die, the wrote another footnote.
}\footnote{
  The point of writing this text is that I can insert this footnote here so that Ulrike can see how
  a footnote looks like. The lipsum package does not insert footnotes.
}


\end{document}
```

I found a way to set the footnotes=multiple after loading the hyperref package, but is this the correct way? Seems to be a bug in the `hyperref` package. Furthermore, when I add the `bidi`package, setting the option after loading the packages does not work any longer ...

Comment: You can try loading scrhack with the option hyperref.

Comment: This had no effect.

Comment: `scrhack` only modifies section heading in `\section`, `\chapter`, `\part` and etc. It has nothing to do with footnotes. See my answer below.

Comment: Holles answer here worked for me: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/40072/incompatibility-between-footmisc-option-multiple-and-hyperref/62091#62091 You can just replace the comma with a colon.

Answer (score 1):

You can either turn of footnote hyperlinks by

```
\usepackage[hyperfootnotes=false]{hyperref}
```

which disables hyperlinking of footnote markers; or manually add `\multiplefootnoteseparator` between `\footnote` commands:

```
\footnote{something}\multiplefootnoteseparator\footnote{whatever}
```

There is no known solution for multiple footnotes and hyperref at the same time, up to date.

> The *hyperref* package has ambitions to make hyperlinks from footnote
>   marks to the corresponding footnote body; naturally this causes grief to
>   *footmisc*, and unfortunately no remedy is currently known...

Comment: “There is no known solution for multiple footnotes and hyperref at the same time, up to date.“ -- Yes, there is: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/28465/multiple-footnotes-at-one-point/71015#71015 :)

Comment: @cgnieder: Thank you! Most specially for `fnpct`. And nice compatibility, by the way!
So should I remove or edit my answer?
By the way, by *no solution*, I was mentioning to footmisc and hyperref.

Comment: Thanks! This also worked for bidi! You should post this as a solution.

Answer (score 1):

Although [this is not its purpose](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/56094/5049) the [`fnpct`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/fnpct) package might be a solution:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage{fnpct}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage{bidi}

\deffootnote[1.5em]{1.5em}{0mm}{\textsuperscript{\normalfont\thefootnotemark}}

\begin{document}

Test\footnote{%
  first footnote%
}\footnote{%
  Second footnote.%
}\footnote{%
  The point of writing this text is that I can insert this footnote here so
  that Ulrike can see how a footnote looks like.  The lipsum package does not
  insert footnotes.%
}\footnote{%
  And if they did not die, the wrote another footnote.%
}\footnote{%
  The point of writing this text is that I can insert this footnote here so
  that Ulrike can see how a footnote looks like. The lipsum package does not
  insert footnotes.%
}

\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]