# Why is package hyperref killing KOMA-Scripts footnote=multiple option?

Tags: hyperref, footnotes, koma-script

I am trying to use KOMA-Scripts `footnotes=multiple` package option together with the hyperref package, but the multiplefootnoteseparator is disappearing.

```
\documentclass[footnotes=multiple]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\deffootnote{1.5em}{1em}{%
    \makebox[1.5em][l]{\thefootnotemark}%
}
\begin{document}
\blindtext\footnote{a}\footnote{b}
\end{document}
```

If I delete the `\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}` line, the footnoteseperator is shown.

It is also possible to insert the footnoteseperator manually using KOMA-Scripts `\multiplefootnoteseparator` option while hyperref package is loaded.

Comment: Use `hyperfootnotes=false`.

Comment: Thanks, this is solving the Problem! Isn't there a possibility to use hyperreffootnotes and the seperator together?

Comment: you can try the fnpct package https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/71015/2388 but I have no idea how well it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Ulrike Fischer wrote in her comment, the `hyperfootnote=false` option of the hyperref package is solving the problem. It brings back the `\multiplefootnoteseperator` at the cost of deactivating hyperreferences for the footnotemarks.

```
\documentclass[footnotes=multiple]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[hidelinks, hyperfootnotes=false]{hyperref}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\deffootnote{1.5em}{1em}{%
    \makebox[1.5em][l]{\thefootnotemark}%
}
\begin{document}
\blindtext\footnote{a}\footnote{b}
\end{document}
```

@Ulrike Fischer also mentioned this [question about multiple footnotes](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/28465/) and the [fnpct package](https://ctan.org/pkg/fnpct) to get a footnoteseperator together with hyperlinked footnotes, but I didn't tried it out.

**Edit:** I've found this [question with similar problem](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/119970) and explanation of the fnpct package solution.