# Formating footnotes with footmisc package

Tags: cross-referencing, footnotes

I used the solution appeared here: [Multiple footnotes at one point](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/28465/multiple-footnotes-at-one-point)
to deal with multiple footnotes referencing from one point. As a minimal example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[multiple]{footmisc}

\begin{document}

Some text.\footnote{A footnote}\textsuperscript{,}\footnote{And another one.}\textsuperscript{,}\footnote{Yet another one.}\textsuperscript{,}\footnote{Yet another one.}\textsuperscript{,}\footnote{The final one.}

\end{document}
```

obtaining

[image]

I want the footnotes appear with the form 1-5 instead of 1,2,3,4,5. I try to use `\textsuperscript{-}` but I do not know how to make all but the first and the last footnote of the series not appear as superscripts.

How is it possible?

Comment: I don't think this is supported by the footmisc package. But I'm curious: Why would you want to reference a range of footnotes?

Comment: @MarcelKrüger   Thanks for the comment. It's the first time that I came across multiple references writing a document. I thought aesthetically it is not so pleasant to let 1,2,3,4,5 appear as a sequence of superscripts. If it is common practice I can leave it as it is.

Comment: The best "cure" for the problem of having five [5!] adjacent footnote markers is not to provide five consecutive `\footnote` statements... Replacing the raised `1,2,3,4,5` string with a raised `1-5` string is, speaking somewhat bluntly, not much of an improvement.

Comment: @Mico I guess it is better to decrease the number of footnotes emanating from the same point. Thanks for the comment. In order to clarify these footnotes are bibliographic references within the page. The main text looks like: "...The appropriate pedagogy in engineering research is a subject of contemporary research...". After research, I wanted to add as footnotes the five references.

Comment: @dimitris - Thanks for this follow-up and explanation. I must confess to seeing no good purpose being served by creating five separate footnotes, one each per citation call-out. Can't you just place all five citations in one footnote?

Comment: @Mico: Initially, it was what I did! (five citation in just one footnote) But I thought it was better with several footnotes emanating from the same point. After the feedback I got, I guess it is better to return to the original situation:-)!